# How do I examine the door in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In the very first mission, after meeting Jacob, I am stuck at a job which says Examine Door. The current job is to defeat the hacked mechs whose army appears to be endless. There appears to be no end to their attack and the map leads to the door which says Examine Door. I am stuck. What shall I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is one of those annoying tutorial things. They want you to order him to use his biotics, so they keep sending guys. Eventually they will give up and let it continue, but you can speed things along by ordering him to slam one of the mechs.

Comment: Now his question makes more sense!

Comment: I just wonder how many mechs they have coz once I almost fought for 2 hours and then gave up

Answer (score 5):

If you're in the room where you meet Jacob (on the bridge, the mechs on the other side), you just have to kill all the mechs (they're definitely not endless) and then talk to Jacob. Then, you'll be able to continue.

Answer (score 1):

There are no endless enemy waves in ME2, simply defeat all the enemies and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I sat there shooting mechs for a half hour and no dice. They just kept coming.

Finally I started the mission over and all you have to do to move on is have the other guy use his power to lift one mech up in the air. It immediately went to a cut scene and we got out of the room.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in another answer.